# Dynamic width of UIScreen elements in Promotion::SplitScreen

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I'm using ProMotion, BubbleWrap, Teacup, and GeoMotion. Having trouble finding the distance from the CGRectMake origin for the navbar to the right edge of the screen. I'd like to fit both portrait and landscape.  Also having trouble putting a navbar across the whole top of the split screens, but I will settle to fix this problem first.  Thank you.

Using Sublime text editor, the autocomplete seems to show me all available methods, no matter what I'm calling them on.

```
class AppDelegate < PM::Delegate
  include PM::Styling
  status_bar true, animation: :none

  def on_load(app, options)
    open_split_screen MenuScreen, DetailScreen

  end

  def set_appearance_defaults
    UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = hex_color("61B637")
  end
end

class MenuScreen < PM::TableScreen
  searchable placeholder: "Search states"

  title "Menu"

  def table_data
    [{
      title: "",
      cells: Menu.all.map { |state| { title: state.name, action: :tapped_state } }
    }]
  end

  def tapped_state(args={})
    PM.logger.debug args
  end

  def states_tapped
  end

  def help_tapped
  end
end

class DetailScreen < PM::Screen
  include DetailStyles

  title "Detail"

  def on_load
    #UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds ???
    width = ???
    naviBarObj = UINavigationBar.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44))
    self.view.addSubview(naviBarObj)
    cancelItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.
      initWithTitle("Cancel", 
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered, 
      target:self, 
      action:'cancelButtonPressed')
    doneItem = UIBarButtonItem.alloc.
      initWithTitle("Done", 
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered, 
      target:self, 
      action:'doneButtonPressed')

    navigItem = UINavigationItem.alloc.initWithTitle("Navigation Title")
    navigItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
    navigItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItem
    naviBarObj.items = NSArray.arrayWithObjects(navigItem, nil)




    self.view.backgroundColor = BW.rgb_color(100, 150, 50)
  end
  def cancelButtonPressed
    true
  end
  def doneButtonPressed
    true 
  end

  def states_tapped
    true
  end

  def help_tapped
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry... need to clarify... When you change orientation, you're trying to get the two views in the split view to resize to fit the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the a view stretched across the detail screen:

```
self.view.frame.size.width
```

If you're trying to get it across the whole screen:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width
```

But what I'd actually suggest is that you make the detail view controller a navigation controller (as I'm pretty sure you want navigation within the detail view) then have the ACTUAL detail view controller as your detail view controller that you have currently, then the navbar will be handled for you.

Last option, as I see you're using "Done" and "Cancel", you might actually be wanting a modal view, not a navigation controller. If you want something to show, then be dismissed from cancelling or from completing an action, a modal view is the way to go.

Comment: I've chalked this trouble onto a glitch and moved on. Thanks for helping.